# How to append ND numpy arrays to (N+1)D numpy array through loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For example I need 30x30 numpy arrays created from images to be fed to a neural net. If I have a directory of images to predict, I should be able to loop through the directory, get image data and create an (n,30,30) shape np array
This is my current method, I intend to reshape each row before feeding to the model

```
def get_image_vectors(path):
    img_list=os.listdir(path)
    print(img_list)
    X=np.empty((900,))
    for img_file in img_list:
        img= Image.open(os.path.join(path,img_file))
        img_grey= img.convert("L")
        resized = img_grey.resize((30,30))
        flattened = np.array(resized.getdata())
        # print(flattened.shape)
        X=np.vstack((X,flattened))
        print(img_file,'=>',X.shape)
    return X[1:,:]
```

Comment: So what's your question?   Do you realize that each call to `vstack` makes a new array?  `vstack` works just as well, if not better, with a list of many arrays.  Notice also that you have to play funny games to get things started, defining that "empty' array (which isn't at all like list `[]`) and then 'delete' it with `[1:]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending to an existing array, it will probably be better to use a list initially, appending to it, and converting to an array at the end. thus saving many redundant modifications of np arrays.

Here a toy example:

```
import numpy as np

def get_image_vectors():
    X= [] #Create empty list
    for i in range(10):
        flattened = np.zeros(900)
        X.append(flattened) #Append some np array to it
    return np.array(X) #Create array from the list
```

With result:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```